# why does VS2013 throw an exception when destroying unique pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Can you provide insight on what this exception means and why it is only thrown when unique_ptr is != nullptr?

Code compiles and runs throwing exceptions.

The unique pointer pFace2 seems to throw an exception when it is being destroyed.
It does not throw an exception when it == nullptr.

The VS2013 exception info is:

> First-chance exception at 0x00CA6A0C in Network.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCD0.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Code is:

```
 for (auto volume : domain) {
        std::cout << "Volume " << volume->getID() << "\n";
        for (auto face : volume->volumeFaces) {

      auto pNeighbourVolume = std::find_if(
          domain.begin(), domain.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<controlVolume> i) {
            return i->getID() == face.getNeighbour();
          });

      if (pNeighbourVolume != domain.end()) {
        std::cout << "  connected to " << (*pNeighbourVolume)->getID() << "\n";

        //This pointer     
        std::unique_ptr<cvVolumeFace> pFace2 = (*pNeighbourVolume)->matchingFace(face); 

        std::cout << "\n";
      } //<- here is where code breaks
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
  }
```

the definition for matching type is:

```
std::unique_ptr<cvVolumeFace> controlVolume::matchingFace(cvVolumeFace &neighboursFace) {
  for (auto face : volumeFaces) {
    if ((face.getNeighbour() == neighboursFace.getNeighbour()) &&
        (face.getArea() - neighboursFace.getArea() < face.matchTolerence())) {      
      std::cout << "Matched faces for " << face.getNeighbour() << " and " << neighboursFace.getNeighbour();
      std::unique_ptr<cvVolumeFace> pFace(&face);
      return pFace;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "ERROR: No matching face to return!\n";
  return nullptr;
};
```

The break occurs in memory.h at line 116

```
void _Decref()
    {   // decrement use count
    if (_MT_DECR(_Mtx, _Uses) == 0)  //<-breaks here
        {   // destroy managed resource, decrement weak reference count
        _Destroy();
        _Decwref();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 0xCCCCCCD0 is a magic number.  It means that you are using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: What is the return type of matchingFace()? 
Unless the call to matchingFace(face) is allocating memory, you shouldn't be using std::unique_ptr. If matchingFace is just returning a pointer from inside a data structure, you code is looping through and deleting objects from inside other data structures.

Comment: Yeah, returning a unique pointer like that smells. It looks like matchingFace should be returning a cvVolume&, though I don't know how RAII open cv classes are.

Comment: Why is it bad practice to return std::unique_ptr<cvVolumeFace>?

Comment: we have a winner: `std::unique_ptr<cvVolumeFace> pFace(&face); return pFace;`

Comment: can you help me understand?  This should create a unique_ptr (new memory allocation) and give it the address of face.  This is then returned (moved) to pFace2.

Comment: @Chris Does pFace exist on the stack or is it on the heap? This is the critical question.

Comment: Is the problem that 'face' is being destroyed when 'pFace2' is destroyed the first time, and then each consecutive time 'pFace2' is created its not pointing to anything?  So this is then an occasion for shared_ptr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `pFace2` is destroyed at the end of the `if (pNeighbourVolume != domain.end()) { ... }` block, and so it will try to delete its resource there; a resource that, in this case, appears to be a local object.

Comment: It is sort of like doing `int x; delete &x;` -- you are deleting something that was not dynamically allocated with an appropriate new expression.. emphasis on *not dynamically allocated*..

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers aren't an excuse to not think about object lifetime in your design. `std::unique_ptr` is a very good way to control lifetime of an object owned by another object or in a limited scope. Generally such a `unique_ptr` should not be passed around - much better to just maintain the ownership with the lifetime of the owner of that `unique_ptr` and pass around raw pointers to other users, *who should never attempt to take ownership*. On the other hand, if lifetime of the various accessors to an object is uncertain, then perhaps a `std::shared_ptr` should be considered. This is a more powerful abstraction, complete with support for weak references, etc., but it is also quite a bit more expensive since it involves a separately allocated control block and a couple of atomic reference counters.